# Rewriting an expression

Tags: combinatorics, regular-expressions

I got the following problem and can't solve it.

Factorize the following statement: C(n+2, n) + C(n+3, n+2). So basically they are asking to rewrite the expression as a X*P expression instead of A+B expression.

I think it has to do something with Pascals formula: C(n, k) = C(n-1, k) + C(n-1, k-1).

Regards!

Comment: You can calculate each term, bring to the common denominator $2$, and add. The expression does not factor nicely. Perhaps you have a typo.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: There is no typo, I have the same problem, it doesn¨t seem to add up with Pascals formula, perhaps it's meant to be solved as the below poster has written it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these basic identities,
$$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}\ \ \ \ \ \ \binom{n}{1} = n\ \ \ \ \ \ \binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
Therefore, 
$$ \binom{n+2}{n} + \binom{n+3}{n+2} = \binom{n+2}{(n+2)-n} + \binom{n+3}{n+3 -(n+2) } $$
$$ = \binom{n+2}{2} + \binom{n+3}{1}$$
The last one equality ends as suggest @Dr.Sonnhard, but because if you can to use in "somewhere" the identity of Pascal (I don't know why), I'd use in the next way
 $$ = \binom{n+2}{2} + \binom{n+3}{1} =\binom{n+2}{2} + \left(\binom{n+2}{0}+\binom{n+2}{1}\right) $$
 $$ = \binom{n+2}{0} + \binom{n+2}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2} $$
By definition:
  $$ = (n+2)!\left(\frac{1}{0!(n+2)!} + \frac{1}{1!(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{2!n!}\right) $$
And, it's a expression with form $x*y$

Btw, answer will be: $n+\frac{1}{2} (n+1) (n+2)+3$

Comment: Thanks alot, I just wanted to know how to do it if it was possible, I am just that person that does get an idea and have to know if it's possible in another way.

Answer (score 0):

by definition we get
$\frac{(n+2)!}{n!\cdot 2}+\frac{(n+3)!}{1!\cdot (n+2)!}=n+3+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)$ and we obtain
$\frac{1}{2}(n^2+5n+8)$
Sonnhard.

Comment: Ok, I had done that, I don't expect you to believe me but isn't there a way to do it with Pascals formula?